# Date returned by REST API in JSON is 8 hours behind what is stored in the Db

Tags: json, spring-boot, rest

I have built a Spring Boot REST API. When called, it would do a query and on a database and returns the results in a JSON back to the caller. What I have noticed is that the one field with the date and time is different from what was stored in the DB. If the DB stores it as 01-01-2020 09:33, in the JSON it is being returned as 01-01-2020 01:33

This is my Controller:

```
//START - retrieveWeekDetails
@GetMapping("{projectId}/detailsForEachWeek")
public ResponseEntity<RestResponseWrapper<List<WeekDto>>> getResources(@PathVariable(value = "projectId", required = false) UUID projectId) {
    List<WeekDto> weekDtoList = projectService.retrieveWeekDetailsById(projectId);
    System.out.println("Iterating...");//debug
    weekDtoList.stream().forEach(elem -> System.out.println(elem));//debug
    return new ResponseEntity<>(new RestResponseWrapper<>(weekDtoList), HttpStatus.OK);
}
//END - retrieveWeekDetails
```

This is my Service:

```
 @Override
public List<WeekDto> retrieveWeekDetailsById(UUID projectId) {
    Iterable<Week> result = weekRepository.findByOriginId(projectId);
    List<WeekDto> returnList = new ArrayList<WeekDto>();
    if ( result != null ) {
        result.forEach(singleResource -> {
            WeekDto weekDtoItem = new WeekDto();
                    weekDtoItem.setOriginId(singleResource.getOriginId());
                    weekDtoItem.setDueDate(singleResource.getDueDate());
                    //weekDtoItem.setDueDate(OffsetDateTime.ofInstant(singleResource.getDueDate().toInstant(), ZoneId.of("UTC")));
            System.out.println(singleResource.getDueDate());//Debug
            System.out.println(weekDtoItem.getDueDate());//Debug
            //
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(singleResource.getDueDate().getTime());
            System.out.println("WEEK_OF_MONTH: " + calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH));//Debug
            //
            System.out.println(OffsetDateTime.ofInstant(singleResource.getDueDate().toInstant(), ZoneId.of("UTC")));//Debug
                    weekDtoItem.setStatus(singleResource.getStatus());

            returnList.add(weekDtoItem);
        });
    }//END : if ( result != null )
    return returnList;
}
```

DTO:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.util.UUID;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class WeekDto {

  private Long id;
  @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss")
  private Timestamp dueDate;
  private UUID originId;
  private String status;

}
```

I have put check points in the form System.out.println() but I can't seem to understand why the date is inaccurate.
Can someone please help. Please let me know is you need more information. Thanks you.

Comment: `WeekDto` serializes the dueDate in the local time format, and, in DB, most probably the dates are saved in UTC format. Try changing the `dueDate` formatter to something like this: `@JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", timezone = "UTC")`

Comment: @Catalin There is still no change. The date returned is still being 8 hours behind what is stored in  the DB.